# no me recarga la pagina ruby on rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola  es quiero que cuando el boolean  cambie a true y guarde vuelva y me recargue la pagina, pero resulta que no la recarga, gracias por la ayuda.
auto es boolean

ReunionesController

```
def auto1
  r = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  r.auto = true
  r.valid?
  p r.errors
  r.save(validate: false)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :show}
  end   
 end
```

routes.rb

```
 get 'reuniones/:id/auto1' => 'reuniones#auto1', as: :auto1
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if @reunion.auto == nil  %>
  <%= link_to 'Autorizar', auto1_path(@reunion.id),remote:true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que recargue la página no necesitas *AJAX*, simplemente utiliza `redirect_to` (en *HTML*) para que se vuelva a cargar la página:

**reuniones_controller.rb**:

```
def auto1
  r = Reunion.find(params[:id])
  r.auto = true
  r.valid?
  p r.errors
  r.save(validate: false)

  redirect_to action: "show", id: r.id
end
```

Quitamos `format` (pues ya no es necesario) y dejamos simplemente `redirect_to :show`, lo que hará que la página *show.html.erb* se cargue de nuevo; es importante notar el uso de `redirect_to` en lugar de `render`, el cual procesará la acción completa (`show`), generando así las variables requeridas por la vista.

**show.html.erb**:

```
<% if @reunion.auto == nil  %>
  <%= link_to 'Autorizar', auto1_path(@reunion.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Simplemente quitamos `remote: true` para que no sea una petición *AJAX*.

Comment: buenos días , me sale el siguiente error lo hice como tu dijiste https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWstzOLQ0LwMHMwcXI3djBuYXc/view?usp=sharing ,gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Oh, error mío, debe ser `redirect_to` en lugar de `redirect`; ya actualicé la respuesta para mostrar el código correcto.

Comment: ya me sale el siguiente error lo hice como tu dijiste, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWstzOLQ0LwRXhXaktkZE5mSGM/view?usp=sharing … ,gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Cierto, dejé la acción como si fuera un `render`; al utilizar `redirect_to` se debe especificar la acción y, cuando sea requerido (como es tu caso), el `id` (e.g. `redirect_to action: "show", id: r.id`). Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: ya me dio gracias

Comment: puede contestar otra pregunta esta si puede https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107297/no-funciona-select2-ruby-on-rails-5 Es de un compañero de estudio gracias